# The symbol less or equal has diagonal bar

Tags: beamer

I'm using beamer. The sybmol "\le" is displayed with a diagonal bar of equality, while I want an horizontal bar of equality, how can this be achieved?

In other words, at the moment I obtain the same result using \le, \leq and \leqslant.

This is the preamble of my document:

````
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathabx, amssymb}
\usepackage{caption, subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs, braket}
\usepackage{xcolor, pifont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, calc}```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store the `\leq` symbol before loading [`mathabx`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathabx) - the root of the change in symbol shape - and then restore it after loading `mathabx`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\let\oldleq\leq % Store current version of \leq in \oldleq
\usepackage{mathabx}
\let\leq\oldleq % Restore old version of \leq from \oldleq

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  $f(x) \leq g(x) \le h(x)$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```